# Python - reading from file into a list

Tags: python

This is simple but I just cant seem to get it right.

I have a text file containing numbers in the form

```
0 1 2
3 43 
5 6 7 8
```

and such.

I want to read these numbers and store it in a list such that each number is an element of a list. If i read the entire file as a string, how can I split the string to get these elements separated?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to store the numbers as ints or strings?

Comment: I do not think regex tag applies here...

Comment: The stupid tagging has already been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the file object as if it were a list of lines:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as handle:
    numbers = [map(int, line.split()) for line in handle]
```

A slightly simpler example:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        print line
```

Comment: Wow. never seen that syntax before!

Answer (score 1):

First, open the file. Then iterate over the file object to get each of its lines and call split() on the the line to get a list of strings. Then convert each string in the list to a number:

```
f = open("somefile.txt")

nums = []
strs = []

for line in f:
    strs = line.split() #get an array of whitespace-separated substrings 
    for num in strs:
         try:
             nums.append(int(num)) #convert each substring to a number and append
         except ValueError: #the string cannot be parsed to a number
             pass
```

nums now contains all of the numbers in the file.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I split the string to get these elements separated

[string.split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)